# Any visual editors for development with JSF component libraries?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, primefaces, frontend

Any visual editors for GUI development with JSF component libraries ?

Comment: You mean a visual editor to drag and drop components on to a page ?

Comment: Not that I know of but it would be cool if you built one :)

Comment: for sure, will let you know if i do so :-)

Comment: @user01 Hi, I don't want to sound as a spammer, but if you are still looking for a visual jsf  tool and are open to trying out a new product, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans supports GUI development. It has all JSF components that can be dragged and dropped in order to build a form.

In eclipse you should install Jboss tools from eclipse market place. It has all bean (component) that can be dragged and dropped to create a form. It has additional support for other tools provided by jboss viz hibernate, richfaces and other. I actually prefer this one :).

Comment: is there a netbeans plugin I need to download for that purpose ? or what version of netbeans ?

Comment: NO plugins required for JSF in netbeans. Use Windows>Palette

Comment: Thanks this helped but I still need to figure out if there are any palettes that have been created for primefaces development. Currently I am seeing palettes JSF & HTML development integrated in netbeans 6.9.

Answer (score 2):

This is for someone who gets the same problem in the future.
I found what `Netbeans` recommends in this page.
http://wiki.netbeans.org/VisualWebSupport